# In French StackOverflow Careers locations overlaps the list of locations

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

Go to [Stack Overflow Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/) and select French at the bottom of the page.

Scroll back up to the top of the page and you'll see the word Emplacements overlapping the text that follows it i.e.

[image: Emplacements overlap]

I imagine this is because it's a longer word than the English equivalent and that the space has not been adjusted from that which English requires. Note that German StackOverflow Careers does not suffer from this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now; I've added some French-specific styling.

Comment: Looks like [there are some more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252284/stackoverflow-careers-edit-links-overlap-images-and-quote-in-french-and-german) :)