# Stackoverflow careers edit links overlap images and quote in French and German

Tags: bug, jobs, design, localization

Log into [StackOverflow careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com), click on the My Profile button at the top right and then scroll down and select either French or German as a language at the bottom.

When you scroll back up you'll find that the translation of the English word Edit overlaps the picture and quote lines as the French modifier and German Bearbeiten translations are longer words and the layout has not been adjusted to account for that. E.g.

[image]